# Directives, ngModelController and viewValue update

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm currently refactoring an old directive of ours, which basically displays a date in the local date format, while keeping an ISO date as the underlying model. I rely on ngModel controller, parsers, formatters and so on. It works mostly as expected, except for one thing.

One datepicker can have a `startBoundary` argument. When set, if the `startBoundary` date is in the future, then the current value of the directive should be set to this `startBoundary`, and the value displayed in the input field updated as well, of course. But so far, even though my modelValue is correctly updated, the value displayed in the field isn't. I've though of a digest issue, but no luck with this so far.

Here's a codepen demonstrating what happens : http://codepen.io/pabuisson/pen/dPRNbb

Any idea how I could solve this ? I don't get it. Thanks a lot guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call `$render:`

```
modelCtrl.$setViewValue moment.utc(start).format( dateFormat )
modelCtrl.$render()
```

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbrPbB